# Yii2 auto login session issue

Tags: php, session, authentication, yii2-advanced-app

I enabled auto login in Yii2 advance app, when user login and checked remember me check box, So he do not require to login even he close the browser. But issue is this, my session not exists that is set after successful login. Here is login function code,

```
public function actionLogin()
{

    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        $user = User::find()->where(['id' => Yii::$app->user->getId()])->one();
        $session = Yii::$app->session;
        $session->set('role_id', $user->role_id);
        $session->set('employer_id', $user->employer_id);

        return $this->goBack();

    } else {
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

roll_id and employer_id not exists in session, when user close the browser and again visit site. Only user id exist in the session because Yii2 framework pick it from Cookies and set into session.

Here is the config file component entries for auto login and session.

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
    ],
    'session' => [
        // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
        'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
    ],
```

how to add roll_id and employer_id in session in case of auto login ?
I did not found code where Yii2 framework set user ID into cookie and set it in session in case of auto login.

Thanks in advance...